# MySQL count on multiple colums with group by

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following colums:

```
id (untique id)
product_matrix (Letter between A-Z to base priicing structre on)
sold (qty of that item sold)
```

if i run this:

```
SELECT `product_matrix` as matrix, count(sold) as qty_sold FROM `products` WHERE `sold` > 0 group by `product_matrix`
```

i get qty sold grouped by the product matrix.

what i would like to get is:

matrix (matrix letter)
qty_sold (count items sold grouped by matrix letter)
products (count of products that have sold within that matrix)

```
Matrix    sold    products
A         12      2
B         6       6
C         1       1
```

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `product_matrix` as matrix, 
        sum(sold) as qty_sold,
        count(id) as products
FROM `products` 
WHERE `sold` > 0 
group by `product_matrix`
```